# Stuck trying to simply a logical expression

Tags: logic

**Simplify:**

$\neg[p \to \neg(p \land q)] $

**My Attempt:**

**1:** $\neg(p \lor \neg(p \land q) \quad \textit{Implication Law} $

**2:** $\neg((p \lor \neg p) \lor q)] \quad \textit{First de Morgan's Law} $

**3:** $\neg(\neg p \lor \neg q) \quad \textit{Second Idempotent Law} $

I am stuck, and cannot decide on the next step. My mind thinks of the **Double Negation** law or alternatively one of the **de Morgan's** laws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Simplify:**
>
> $\neg[p \to \neg(p \land q)] $
>
> **My Attempt:**
>
> **1:** $\neg(p \lor \neg(p \land q) \quad \textit{Implication Law} $

No.  That should be $\neg(\color{red}\neg p \lor \neg(p \land q)$

> **2:** $\neg((p \lor \neg p) \lor q)] \quad \textit{First de Morgan's Law} $

No.  Applying DeMorgan on  $\neg(p \lor \neg(p \land q)$ should get you $\neg(p \lor (\neg p \lor \color{red} \neg q))$.  You also need to apply an Association to move the parentheses like you did. And you have an extra closing $]$

> **3:** $\neg(\neg p \lor \neg q) \quad \textit{Second Idempotent Law} $

No. You can't apply Idempotence on your $\neg((p \lor \neg p) \lor q)$. You need two identical disjuncts (like $p \lor p$ or $\neg p \lor \neg p$, but you have $p \lor \neg p$). But had you done the first steps correct, you would have been able to do an Idempotence after all:

$\neg (p \to \neg(p \land q))$

**1:** $\neg(\neg p \lor \neg(p \land q) \quad \textit{Implication Law} $

**2:** $\neg(\neg p \lor (\neg p \lor \neg q)) \quad \textit{de Morgan's Law} $

**3:** $\neg((\neg p \lor \neg p) \lor \neg q) \quad \textit{Association} $

**4:** $\neg(\neg p \lor \neg q) \quad \textit{Idempotence} $

**5:** $\neg \neg p \land \neg \neg q \quad \textit{de Morgan's} $

**6:** $p \land q \quad \textit{Double Negation} $

Answer (score 0):

$\phi\rightarrow \psi$ is logically equivalent to $\neg \phi \lor 
\psi$ (sometimes called the **implication law**).

1. $\therefore \neg(p\rightarrow \neg(p\land q)) = \neg(\neg p \lor \neg(p\land q))$

$\neg(\neg \phi \lor \neg \psi)$ is logically equivalent to $\phi\land\psi$

2. $\therefore \neg(\neg p \lor \neg (p\land q)) = p \land (p\land q)$ (this is one of **De Morgan's Laws**).

$\land$ is **associative**, IE: $\phi\land(\psi\land\chi)$ is equivalent to $(\phi\land\psi)\land\chi$,

So we can write $p\land(p\land q)$ as $(p\land p)\land q$.

This $p\land p$ is equivalent to just $p$. Therefore the answer is $p\land q$. You might have figured out this last step by looking at $p\land(p\land q)$ but this is the more detailed reason why.

This can be verified using a truth table.